# dmtracedump is not producing the output file

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have installed graphviz-2.38, and I have included the dmtracedump path inorder to execute from command line. I am trying to view call graph of the .trace file stored in my system. I executed the below command, but it seems to be not working as no output files have been generated. Please help in resolving the error.

```
C:\Users\rb>dmtracedump -ho -s D:\Android\logs\cpu-art-single-call.trace -g D:\Android\logs\be cpu-art-single-call.trace

C:\Users\rb>
```